# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'люди' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' on line 23

Tags: php, mysql, sql

помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку:

```
<?php
$login = filter_var (trim($_POST['login']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$pass = filter_var (trim($_POST['pass']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$dblpass = filter_var (trim($_POST['dblpass']),
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (mb_strlen($login) < 6 || mb_strlen($login) > 90) {
    echo "Длина логина не допустима";
    exit();
}

if (mb_strlen($pass) < 6 || mb_strlen($pass) > 90) {
    echo "Длина пароля меньше 6-ти символов не допустима";
    exit();
}


$mysql = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','root','mybd');
$mysql -> query ('INSERT INTO 'люди' (Логин_Человек, Пароль_Человек)
VALUES($login, $pass)');
$mysql -> close();

?>
```

Comment: Установите любую IDE, и синтаксические ошибки вы будете выявлять на этапе набора кода.

Comment: у меня нет возможности установить IDE.

Comment: да лаааадно. вы на листочке пишите код?

Comment: очевидно в редакторе кода.

Comment: Редактор требует наличия соответствующего оборудования. IDE требует того же. Так что проблем не вижу)

Comment: Даже легковесные редакторы тип sublime и PHPEdit, phpDesigner подсвечивают ошибки

Comment: вы по факту сможете помочь найти ошибку или будете советовать что установить?
Мне и нашли ошибку в 23 строке, я не знаю как ее решить, в заголовке сама ошибка
$mysql -> query ('INSERT INTO 'люди' (Логин_Человек, Пароль_Человек)

Comment: Ответ в ответе.

Comment: cпасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ поможет, то можно и галочкой отметить, что напротив ответа)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL требует указания наименования таблиц в обратных кавычках, а не прямых. Прямые лишь закрыли и открыли строку заново, что создало ошибку в районе слова "люди"

```
$mysql -> query ('INSERT INTO `люди` (Логин_Человек, Пароль_Человек)
                              ^--  ^---
                  VALUES($login, $pass)');
```